# How can I finish this mobile-only hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have a hamburger menu on my site that only appears at 600px or less. I'd like for my categories to be under this icon. This would entail making those menu items disappear off of the green nav bar at the 600px threshold, then reappear under that hamburger. What is the best way to accomplish this?

[Here is the live view of the site](https://cloud.e.activehealth.com/BYBO) and here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #47a23f;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #005da6;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #47a23f;
  min-width: 13%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 5% 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
  color:#fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  color:#fff;
}

  .topnav > .active {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.topnav:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.topnav > .active:hover {
  background-color: #005da6;
}

.dropdown-content > .active {
  background-color: #003150;
}

.dropdown-content:hover > .active {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content > .active:hover {
  background-color: #003150;
}
  
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 /* .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;} */
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  } 
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>



<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="https://cloud.e.activehealth.com/BYBO/Home" class="active">Home</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Workforce 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a target="blank" href="https://myactivehealth.com/Portal/PreRegistrations/Index">Request to enroll</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/Registration/RegistrationStep1?IsoAuthDPRequest=False">Create an account</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/PortalLogin.aspx?SupplierURL=15571">Log in</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="https://cloud.e.activehealth.com/BYBO/Employer">Employer</a></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Injured Workers 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
 <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/Registration/RegistrationStep1?IsoAuthDPRequest=False">Create an account</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.myactivehealth.com/Portal/PortalLogin.aspx?SupplierURL=15571">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1) the hamburger menu must toggle the entirety of the navbar (from display none, to display block or flex and vise versa). 2) you must re-style your nav items / links to be however you like them, below the 600px threshold.

Comment: Here is an example of how I styled it through the Chrome dev tools, using flex: https://gyazo.com/25e2cd32bc1bcbf37f630f5471373bf6

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS changes, utilizing flex, I am able to get this result:

[image: Mobile example]

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #myTopnav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    #myTopnav > a:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: #47a23f;
        order: 1;
    }
    #myTopnav > div.dropdown {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #myTopnav > div.dropdown:nth-child(2) {
        order: 3;
    }
    #myTopnav > div.dropdown:nth-child(3) {
        order: 2;
    }
    #myTopnav > div.dropdown:nth-child(4) {
        order: 4;
    }
    #myTopnav > a:last-child {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        float: none;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

It is up to you to fine-tune it. I.e. add a class or something for display logic to display none to elements initially, and then give them the appropriate display property upon toggling the hamburger menu. This is the last bit of CSS and JS required.